# How to run Retrovit2 Json RecyclerView in fragment?

Tags: json, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

So i using retrofit2 to fetch my json into my main activity it runs smoothly, but im using bottom navigation so i should convert my code from activity into fragment.

my code didnt show error after i debug it, it shows force close when the fragment opened

This is my Fragment Code:

```
package com.itsalex.helios.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.itsalex.helios.Adapter;
import com.itsalex.helios.ApiClient;
import com.itsalex.helios.ApiInterface;
import com.itsalex.helios.Contact;
import com.itsalex.helios.R;
import com.itsalex.helios.activity.CartActivity;
import com.itsalex.helios.activity.ProdukActivity;
import com.itsalex.helios.adapters.HorizontalAdapter;
import com.itsalex.helios.adapters.VerticalAdapter;
import com.itsalex.helios.model.Food;
import com.itsalex.helios.model.GeneralFood;
import com.itsalex.helios.recycleFragment;
import com.itsalex.helios.rest.RetrofitClient;
import com.itsalex.helios.rest.RetrofitInterface;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public StatusFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    /*private appController mController;*/
    public List<Contact> contacts;
    public Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    protected Handler handler;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView search;
    String[] item;

    private Call<ResponseBody> result;

    public static recycleFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        recycleFragment fragment = new recycleFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, container, false);

        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.prograss);
        recyclerView   = v.findViewById(R.id.frg_recyclerView);

        handler = new Handler();
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), contacts, recyclerView, recyclerView, false);
        adapter = new Adapter(contacts, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        fetchContact("users", "");
        return  v;
    }

    public void fetchContact(String type, String key){

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<Contact>> call = apiInterface.getContact(type, key);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                contacts = response.body();
                adapter = new Adapter(contacts, getContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error\n"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }




    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        /*if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

this is my adapter activity

```
package com.itsalex.helios;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Contact> contacts;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Contact> contacts, Context context) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        holder.email.setText(contacts.get(position).getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name,email;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Logcat it shows error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.itsalex.helios.Adapter.getItemCount(Adapter.java:40)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3722)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3527)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:894)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2185)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

i google it and i didnt find the answer, what should i do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialised your progress bar.Use findViewById to set progressbar to your required progressbar.

Comment: thank you i miss that progressbar, but after i add progressbar it show me more error in logcat

Comment: i updated the code, i still got an error at adapter im tryin google the error changelog and still can fetch the recyclerview

Comment: Thats because you havent initialised contacts. Add contents to contacts then call adapter.Using contacts.add(new Contact(/*your data here*/));